# iphone/ipad app deployment with iphone configuration tool

Tags: iphone, ipad, deployment, enterprise

i can't really find an answer to that question.

We have an in-house app I would like to deploy as default app with the iphone configuration tool. But I don't see the possibility to add the app (ipa or plist) somewhere in that list of options.

I thought this was possible?

Any clue how to do this?

Regards

Comment: @spankmasterHello, can you please tell me how to distribute my application to around 100 employees using Enterprise program.I don't want to add their device UDID. I have searched but i didn't find any good way apart from TestFlight.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There's two Apple articles you should be looking at.

1) is [Distributing Enterprise Apps for iOS 4 Devices](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/FA_Wireless_Enterprise_App_Distribution/Introduction/Introduction.html)

(which does refer to the iPhone Configuration Utility; the section you want to read is "Installing Apps Using iPhone Configuration Utility")

and then of course,

2) the [iPhone Configuration Utility documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/FA_iPhone_Configuration_Utility/Introduction/Introduction.html) itself.

Comment: thx, but what I meant is building a configuration with the iphone configuration utility having apps included. The described way is either through over-the-air distribution or having the device connected to the mac/pc running the iphone configuration utility

Comment: basicallly - I want to create a configuration that sets settings and installs an in-house app with it

Comment: @MichaelHello, can you please tell me how to distribute my application to around 100 employees using Enterprise program.I don't want to add their device UDID. I have searched but i didn't find any good way apart from TestFlight.Thanks